Categorical Definition of Galois Group?
Field extensions may be viewed as monomorphisms up to isomorphism. That is, given a field monomorphism $\varphi : k \to L$, there exists a (unique?) extension $L/k'$ where $k' \subseteq L$ and $k' \cong k$. Notably, any non-trivial field morphism is mono, so the "category of field extensions" is essentially the non-trivial subcategory of $\text{Arr}(\mathsf{Fld})$, whose objects are, namely, the non-trivial field morphisms.
This perspective, if valid, allows us to define a morphism of field extensions $\iota : k \to \hat{k} , \kappa : F \to \hat{F}$ as a pair of (non-trivial) field morphisms, $(\mu, \lambda)$ making the following diagram commute:

But then the usual categorical automorphism group of a field extension $k \to L$ does not align with the definition from Galois theory. The former is the set of automorphism pairs $(\mu : k \to k, \lambda : L \to L)$ such that $\iota \mu = \lambda \iota$, whereas the latter is the set of $L$-automorphisms $\lambda$ such that $\iota \text{id}_k = \lambda \iota$, with $\iota : k \to L$ being the inclusion map.
My question is whether these are equivalent in some sense, and if not, whether there is a natural reason we try to fix $\text{id}_k$. That is, would anything differ we fix some other $k$-automorphism instead of $\text{id}_k$?

At this level galois theory doesn't behave as categorically nicely as you would like, basically because field extensions don't need to be unique, so functoriality is lost. (eg. algebraic closure cannot be made into a functor). Where the categories become useful is not in the concrete details of field extensions, but in the high level connection between the poset (category) of subextensions and the poset (category) of closed subgroups. See the generalizations here, for instance.

See also the discussion here

You can get the abstract group from the category of field extensions of $k$, sure. But the Galois group also has topology, and that is not so easy to describe.

Instead of looking at the whole arrow category of $\mathrm{Fld}$, look only at the slice under $k$, i.e. $\mathrm{Fld}^{k/}$. An object in this category is a field $L$ together with a (mono)morphism $i:k\to L$. An arrow $f:(L,i)\to(L',i')$ in this category is a morphism $f:L\to L'$ that commutes with $i$ and $i'$. Then the automorphism group of an extension $(L,i)$ is just $\mathrm{Aut}(L,i)$.
In particular, if $(L,i)$ is a Galois extension, then $\mathrm{Gal}(L : k) = \mathrm{Aut}(L,i)$.
Observe that The category $\mathrm{Arr}(\mathrm{Fld})$ has a functor to $\mathrm{Fld}$ that sends an arrow $k\to L$ to just $k$: this is the "domain" functor $\mathrm{dom}:\mathrm{Arr}(\mathrm{Fld})\to\mathrm{Fld}$. Then $\mathrm{Fld}^{k/}$ is the "fibre" of this functor that lies over $k$:
$$\mathrm{Fld}^{k/}=\mathrm{dom}^{-1}(k),$$
i.e. the objects that $\mathrm{dom}$ sends to $k$ and the arrows between them that $\mathrm{dom}$ sends to the identity $\mathrm{id}_k$.

You wrote

given a field monomorphism $\varphi : k \to L$, there exists a (unique?) extension $L/k'$ where $k' \subseteq L$ and $k' \cong k$.

This is not true.  Let $L = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ and $k = \mathbf Q[x]/(x^4-2)$. There are two subfields $k'$ of $L$ that are isomorphic to $k$: $k' = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $k' = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{2}i)$. Moreover, for each $k'$ there are two monomorphisms $\varphi : k \to L$ where $\varphi(k) = k'$. They can be described by $x \mapsto \pm\sqrt[4]{2}$ when $k' = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $x \mapsto \pm i\sqrt[4]{2}$ when $k' = \mathbf Q(i\sqrt[4]{2})$.

That's a good point, and precisely why I put the question mark there. There is definitely some subtlety in this. Perhaps the extension is unique if it is Galois? But does this undermine or answer my question? Can we impose some condition on the category to avoid such a situation, and perhaps that would coincide with the "fixing" property?

Being Galois does not make extensions unique: that is how Galois groups are nontrivial.  My example is Galois: $L/k'$ is Galois for both choices of $k'$.
